# How to create one more registation page in drupal site

Tags: 7, users, nodes

In our drupal site we have a Registration page. and the new requirement is creating the one more registration page with same functionality(newly created registration page also use same database to store the user details)

Any ideas for implementing this in drupal is appreciated.

Comment: What is the end goal here? There are multiple ways to do this, the best way will depend on what problem you trying to solve by creating a new registration page.

Comment: You may need to try using profile2 module.

Comment: Hi Jaypan, there are two kind of products, so each one have to use different registration pages and both reg data should store in same database only.

Answer (score 2):

If you need different registration forms for different types of users, you can experiment with the following modules.

https://www.drupal.org/project/profile2
https://www.drupal.org/project/profile2_regpath

Answer (score 1):

No need to use Profile2 Module to have different registration forms, you can use [Auto Assign Role](https://www.drupal.org/project/autoassignrole) Module and it will allow you to create as many as you want registration pages (/admin/config/people/autoassignrole/pages), also you can assign specific role when user registered using specific registration path or just used the normal role authenticated user.

Try it now on [simplytest.me](https://simplytest.me/project/autoassignrole)