# Unable to post new forum topics in Drupal site

Tags: 7, nodes

When I try to post a new forum topic getting this error

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 157286400 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 91 bytes) in /sai/vij/modules/field/field.attach.inc on line 696

i have a free space of 4389 MB in server. and I given a memory_size as -1 in php.info file.

```
     Any ideas for implementing this in drupal is appreciated.
```

Comment: You probably need to increase your PHP's `memory_limit` from `128M` to `256M`. If you're using C-Panel, I am sure there is an option for that somewhere. If you use SSH command line, then you just need to edit the PHP's php.ini file and remember to restart apache

Comment: After increasing the memory limit to 256M, same error i am geeting. any help.

Comment: Are you sure the 256M has kicked in? Check your `/admin/reports/status` and see if it says 256M there.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! sssweat, now i can able to do new posting in forum.  i am new to drupal could you please help on this issue http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/224644/how-to-create-one-more-registation-page-in-drupal-site

Comment: The answers already given there are good, you should try them out.

Answer (score 1):

Yes i think @No Sssweat is right. You need to increase PHP memory limit.

`ini_set('memory_limit', '256M');` in your **sites/default/settings.php** file.

Increase PHP memory limit

Increase PHP's memory limit, e.g. to increase it to 256M you could try adding:

```
memory_limit = 256M to your server's main php.ini file (recommended, if you have access)
memory_limit = 256M to a php.ini file in the Drupal root
ini_set('memory_limit', '256M'); in your sites/default/settings.php file
php_value memory_limit 256M in your .htaccess file in the Drupal root
```

Comment: In your last code snippet are lines 3 and 4 other ways to do it? Because from my experience making the change in the php.ini file alone is enough.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! smalution, now i can able to do new posting in forum. i am new to drupal could you please help on this issue  http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/224644/how-to-create-one-more-registation-page-in-drupal-site

Comment: Yes @No Sssweat I am agree by changing the memory limit on php.ini is enough. I just added different way to achieve same. Thank You :)